# Quick way to find my location (google maps v2)

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I am making an application where i want to sort a list of points of interest according to my current location.
So every time the user will click to see a list of points of interest (e.g. hotels), the application has to find my location and then sort the list according to the distance (nearest first).
I do not want to show my location at the map and i am not interest to correct my location often.

I just want a quick way to find my location every time the user clicks to see the list of pois and then i will calculate the distance and update my database...

How can i do it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use the Last known location. Plz refer Android Developer Guide :[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#FastFix)

Comment: ok i getLastKnownLocation. But after that i want to check if i have moved and have a new location..

Comment: getLastKnownLocation() can be used only for getting last known location. For accuracy purpose, you have to use GPS only. Although you can also try using NETWORK_PROVIDER (see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER) to get more accurate location from lastKnownLocation (but this may take some time to get location)